# SELECT COUNT TROUBLE IN QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I just need simple QUERY - MYSQL FOR MY DASHBOARD. USING LINE CHARTS AND AREA CHARTS..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LQYH.png)

Citizentable

1. citizenid
2. citizencensusyear(fK of censusyeartable)
3. citizengender

censusyeartable

1. censusyearid

   2. censusyear

expected output:

1. censusyear
2. total male
3. totalfemale

I JUST CAN'T FIGURE OUT HOW TO GET THE EXACT VALUE..

CAN ANYBODY HELP ME PLEASE

Comment: come up with real mysql tables, and with your stuffs

Comment: sIR, THAT'S THE EXACT COLumns of my table

Comment: exact value of ?

Comment: I have Citizentable with columns CitizenID, CitizenGender,CitizenCensusYear an censusyeartable with censusyearid and censusyear 

I need to have an output of

CensusYear                   total male                     total female
2016                                   25                                  24
2017                                    21                                  21
2018                                  11                                    11

Comment: Question tells us absolutely -------

Comment: what exact value of ?

Comment: @CSPPurposes Pls Edit the question instead of putting all that detail in commment

Comment: i mean in the image attached. I illustrated the tables and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a query like this:

```
select  
censusyear,
sum(case CitycenGender when 'Male' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total Male',
sum(case CitycenGender when 'Female' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total Male'
from CitycenTable
inner join CensusYearTable on CityCensusYear = CensusYearID
```

Regards.

Comment: thanks a lot i did not figure it out, i even thought of having selecting from a select statement. Thanks sir.

Comment: You are welcome ;)